# Can I subscribe to any page on Facebook for Realtime Updates?

Tags: c#, facebook

I can not figure out if I can create an application(native windows) that has a subscription to any given facebook page? or is only my own apps I am allowed to?

An example: Given http://www.facebook.com/natholdet, would i then be able to get a notification in my app that a new post on the wall have been posted, or do i need to check it every now and then? (are there any limites from facebook on how offen i can check it).

Comment: You should be able to do anything you can through a browser.  So can you subscribe to that page?  I don't make a habit of clicking random Facebook pages.

Comment: i am talking about this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/):

"Page - Get notifications when **pages that have installed your app as a Tab** change some of their public properties"

`Similarly, for Page objects, you can only subscribe to changes to public attributes of the page, such as name, category, and picture.`

Hence, there is no realtime updates for posts anyways.

Comment: pages that have installed your app as a Tab  : thats not the case anyhow

Comment: Right, its a little outdated. But the same principles probably apply.